# vector.size() returns 0 all the time

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector

I have the following class:

```
class MyVector{
public:
    MyVector(int num);
    virtual ~MyVector();
    int my_size();
private:
    vector<int> some_vector;
};
```

The constructor and size function look like this:

```
MyVector::MyVector(int num) {
    vector <int> some_vector(num); 
}

int MyVector::my_size() {
    return this->some_vector.size();
```

However when running these lines:

```
MyVector *Bul = new MyVector(5);
    cout << Bul->my_size() << endl;
```

The output is 0. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I advise you to make some research on initializer lists in C++.

Comment: Unrelated: You do not have to use a pointer and `new` for `Bul`. `MyVector Bul(5);` should be sufficient and easier to manage.

Comment: Increase the warning level to your compiler.  It should be able to tell you about the local variable name hiding the member variable name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your constructor makes a local variable that shadows your member variable

```
MyVector::MyVector(int num) {
    vector<int> some_vector(num); 
}
```

Instead use the member initialization list

```
MyVector::MyVector(int num)
  : some_vector(num)
{
}
```